# How to use 3.3 V FTDI Serial Cable with LeMaker Hikey 620 which has 1.8v UART signals

Tags: serial, uart, ftdi

I have FTD Serial Cable TTL-232R-3V3 which operates on 3.3V.
https://ftdi-uk.shop/collections/usb-cables-ttl/products/ttl-232r-3v3-2mm

I was trying to use it on my Hikey LeMaker for an hour with no success. Then I realised that the signal levels are different which might be the reason that I was not able to establish a serial connection.
On LeMAKER Hikey, [user guide](https://github.com/96boards/documentation/blob/master/consumer/hikey/hikey620/hardware-docs/HiKey_Hardware_User_Manual_Rev0.2.pdf), UART3 uses 1.8V signals and hence its perhaps not compatible with my FTDI Serial cable which operates on 3.3V

Is there a way/hack so that I can use this 3.3 V cable on hikey? I am not good in electronics, so cosider me noob. Can I take use of 1.8 V from Hikey Board or can I use a similar trick like this one : 
https://discuss.96boards.org/t/1-8v-uart-ttl-to-usb-diy-for-around-5-for-ce-boards/1911

Or can we use bi-directional logic converter here, something like this : https://robu.in/product/level-converter-4-channel/?

Comment: Level converter would be the cleanest option. But you don't need it bidirectional, you will need one for 1.8->3.3 and one for 3.3->1.8.

Comment: Be careful. If you connected a 3.3V serial-USB cable to a 1.8V device, you may have already burned out the RX pin on the 1.8V device.

Comment: @DoxyLover : Oops.... Hope the Hikey had some protection mechanisms, because I connected on all three UARTs available and they might have burned out by now.... :(

Comment: Is there a way that I can verify the UART pins are not damaged?

Comment: @EugeneSh. : `you don't need bidirectional` ? But the converter itself says its bidirectional. Do I need to use a different converter? Or can you please explain the circuit in brief. I am not an electronics engineer, so pretty bad at it.